# How to create a react native dropdown text picker?

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, react-native-paper

[image]

How to create a dropdown text picker, as shown in the picture, in react native, using react-native-paper *TextInput* and react native autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use react-native-autocomplete-dropdown library from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-dropdown

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).